# How to know which reading of 細やか to use

Tags: kanji, readings

細やか can be either read as こまやか or ささやか

But how do I differentiate which reading to read it as? (if there is no furigana)

Or can they be used interchangeably?

Comment: ほそやか is possible, too, although that is even more archaic. https://kotobank.jp/word/%E7%B4%B0%E3%82%84%E3%81%8B-504491

Comment: I see, I've seen ほそい before but not ほそやか

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ささやか is almost always written in all hiragana, and 細やか without furigana is almost always read as こまやか. I believe most native Japanese speakers don't even know ささやか can be written as 細やか in kanji (FWIW, I didn't). As for the meaning, ささやか and こやまか have very different meanings, and they are never interchangeable.